# Why my contact form cannot be displayed after adding PHP Form Validation code?

Tags: php, html, css

I am new to php. I am trying to add a validated contact form to my website. The contact form was appearing perfectly in the browser (before adding validation code) but after adding PHP form validation the contact form cannot be displayed anymore. Please help me to figure out the loophole in my code.
I have added the screenshot of my contact page (after adding form validation code).

[image]

```
<section id="contact" class= my-5>
      <div class= py-5>
          <h2 class=text-center>Contact Us</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="w-50 m-auto">
      <?php

    print_r($_POST);

   function has_header_validation($str)
      {

         return preg_match("/[\r\n]" , $str);
      }

   if (isset($_POST['contact_submit'])) 
     {
         $name= trim($_POST['name']);
         $email= trim($_POST['email']);
         $sub= trim($_POST['subject']);
         $msg= ($_POST['message']);


   if (has_header_validation($name) || has_header_validation($email) || has_header_validation($sub)) 
      {
         die();
      }

  if (!$name || !$email || !$subject) 
    {
         echo '<h2>All Fields Required.</h2><a href="contact.php" class="button block">Go back.</a>';
         exit();
     }

    $to = "youremail@gmail.com";

   $subject = "$name via SeePic form : $sub";

   $message = "Name: $name\r\n";
   $message .= "Email: $email\r\n";
   $message .= "Message: \r\n$msg";

   $message = wordwrap($message, 72);


  $header = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
  $header .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
  $header .= "Form: $name <$email> \r\n";
  $header .= "X-Priority: 1\r\n";

  mail($to , $subject , $message , $header);

 ?>
<h3>Thanks for contacting us!</h3>
<h4>Please allow us 24hrs for a response.</h4>
<a href="">Go back Home page</a>

<?php } else{ ?>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method=POST>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label>Full Name</label>
           <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter your full name" 
           class="form-control">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
           <label>Username</label>
           <input type="text" name="email" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Username/Email" 
            class="form-control">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
           <label>Subject</label>
           <input type="text" name="subject" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Title of your 
            message/query" class="form-control">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
           <label>Your Message</label><br>
           <textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Write your message/query 
             here.."></textarea>
         </div>
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark" name="contact_submit" value="send 
             message">Submit</button>
         </form>

    <?php } ?>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Because you `exit()` in your (faulty) `if` clause `if (!$name || !$email || !$subject)`. `$subject` is never set, it's `$sub`

Comment: On page load $name, $email and $subject are all empty so your script hits exit() straight away. !$subject should also be !$sub

Comment: @Coffeebean That code will only be executed if `$_POST['contact_submit']` is set, not on initial page load

Comment: @kerbh0lz Yes well spotted. Didn't see the whole thing wrapped in that statement.